# opencart 2.1.0.2 order appear in missing order

Tags: checkout, opencart2.x

I have a few completed orders but for some reasons they all appear under "Missing Orders" status. But when I click to edit the order, I am getting the error "undefined and unable to edit".

Comment: Please add code snippets

Comment: Sorry i am not programming expert. What do you mean add code snippets?thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might get better help directly from the OpenCart folks at http://www.opencart.com/?route=support/support